# Why the ACI context I created successfully is not visible when I execute the command "docker context ls" in another computer?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azure-container-instances

I deployed a Docker container on Azure following these instructions:

https://docs.docker.com/cloud/aci-integration/

To be more precise, I deployed a multi-container application (WordPress) in ACI with Docker-Compose and a docker-compose.yml. Everything went smooth.

If I go to the Azure portal, I can see the Container instance and the containers I created. If  run the command `docker context ls` in the command prompt (after the command `docker login azure`), I can see the default context and the one I created.

The problem is that if I run the command `docker context ls` on another computer, I can see only the default context. Same result if I run `docker login azure --tenant-id xxx`.

What am I missing? Is there a way to see the contexts using the Azure Portal?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, it does what it should do. The context just uses the account that you use for the command `docker login azure` with its permission, but it does not belong to the account. It seems the two computers are not in the same cluster, so the context just works and is stored in the local of the computer, not for another one. Learn more about the [Docker context](https://docs.docker.com/engine/context/working-with-contexts/).